# Insert multiple images in a single PDF according to image.coordinates - Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, reportlab

I have a image path's and corresponding coordinates as a dict. Ex: 
                        {'coords': [u'530,88,592,99'],
                         'filepath': 1.jpg},
                        {'coords': [u'7,12,152,85'],
                         'filepath': 2.jpg},
                        {'coords': [u'448,12,594,86'],
                         'filepath': 3.jpg}
I would like to generate a single PDF with all the images as per the relative-coordinates of the images. I guess, it might be possible with reportlab, but no initial luck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `reportlab` for this purpose. `drawImage` can be used for image drawing in `Pdf`.

`drawImage` arguments.

```
drawImage(image, x, y, width=None, height=None, mask=None, preserveAspectRatio=False, anchor='c')
```

- “image” may be an image filename or an ImageReader object.
- x and y define the lower left corner of the image you wish to draw
- If width and height are given, the image will be stretched to fill the given rectangle bounded by (x, y, x+width, y-height).

**Example program:**

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
# move the origin up and to the left
c.translate(inch,inch)
c.setFillColorRGB(1,0,1)
c.drawImage("image1.jpg", 10, 10, 50, 50)
c.drawImage("image2.jpg", 60, 60, 50, 50)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

This program should generate a pdf `test.pdf` with two images in the corresponding coordinates.Now you can parse coordinates and images from your `coords` dictionary.

**Let:**

```
 coords_dict = {'coords': [u'7,12,152,85'], 'filepath': 2.jpg}
```

Then `drawImage` for your dict should be

```
 c.drawImage(
    coords_dict["filepath"], 
    coords_dict["coords"][0], 
    coords_dict["coords"][1],
    coords_dict["coords"][3]-coords_dict["coords"][0],
    coords_dict["coords"][4]-coords_dict["coords"][2])
```

For more info please [check](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/pdfgen.html)

Comment: If the OP does not upvote, at least I do... showing a working example to someone who put so few effort into the question shows positive attitude ;).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Thanks for your compliment :)

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, regardless of reputation count, up-vote shall be there for all new stack-overflow users.

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv This was so helpful, Reportlab documentation didn't helped me than your straight solution. Thanks for that :)

Comment: I figured that who can "accept" an answer can also upvote it. Sorry for that assumption!

Answer (score 0):

Reportlab is feature-rich and complex. For your task, it will for sure work, but there may be alternatives. I recommend having a look at either of those actively maintained projects:

- PyFPDF (https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf):

  > PyFPDF is simple, small and versatile, with advanced capabilities and
  >   easy to learn, extend and maintain.

  The [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Tutorial) shows how to add an image to a page, and it seems to be as easy as `self.image('logo_pb.png', 10, 8)`
- cairocffi (https://pythonhosted.org/cairocffi/):

  > cairocffi is a CFFI-based drop-in replacement for Pycairo, a set of
  >   Python bindings and object-oriented API for cairo. Cairo is a 2D
  >   vector graphics library with support for multiple backends including
  >   image buffers, PNG, PostScript, PDF, and SVG file output.

  There, it seems you would create a `cairocffi.PDFSurface()` and then create a `ImageSurface()` for all of your images, and add the images to the PDF.